# JPA mapping the same child relationship twice(different cardinality) in same parent class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

Given 2 objects, Person and Phone, wherein their relationship is Person(one)-Phone(many).
The Phone has variable type which can have 4 possible values: Residential, Office, Mobile, Fax.

Is it possible to map the Phone relationship twice in Person such as below:

```
class Person {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
   <Phone> phones; //this is for : Residential, Office, Fax only

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
   Phone mobile; //this is for Mobile
}


class Phone {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk")
   Person person;
}
```

The reason for the segregation is that there are screens wherein I would display mobile number but not require loading the other phone numbers, so I was thinking that I don't need jpa to load all phones into a list and just need mobile...

Is this something that can be done? If so, is it normal practice?

Answer (score 2):

I think your example is not going to work, as you in fact have multiple `Phone`s for each person.  Hibernate is not going to distinguish from the phones and map the mobile to your `mobile`

Unless you subclass your phone for each type of phone, and given you have a `MobilePhone` class, you can change your `Person` to

```
class Person {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
   <Phone> phones; //this is for : Residential, Office, Fax only

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
   MobilePhone mobile; //this is for Mobile
}
```

This should work (I believe :P )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way for "List<Phone> phones" variable to be mapped to only Resident,Off and Fax? How can I tell the mapping to exclude Mobile from the "List<Phone> phones" variable?

Comment: the only way I can thought of now is, to have a inheritance hierarchy that Resident, Office and Fax share one base class, while Mobile another.  However that's sooooo uglyyyyyy.... Honestly, is that really make sense to map something like this?  Why don't make that be the behavior of Person instead?  Simply have all kinds of phone in the list, and provide method in Person as something like `Phone getMobile()`.  It makes more sense to me

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was just trying to avoid hitting the DB and getting all phones when I just wanted the Mobile one...

Comment: My suggestion is: Don't bother for these kind of pre-mature optimization.  It is not a huge record for each row of Phone.  Sometimes a simple query which gets more records outperform a complicated query which gets less records.  And, the optimization can be achieved by other way instead of in terms of entity relationship.  e.g. by a query which retrieve only people and corresponding phone which is mobile.  My suggestion is keep the model design reasonable in your design, and keep such workaround or tricks as a last resort in case you cannot solve the problem by other ways

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? It is perfectly valid, but you could also consider tagging the `Phone` class with a type (you'll need that anyway to distinguish between residential, office etc.) and unless you live in a country with *really* long phone numbers, the overhead of fetching them all isn't that big :-)

Cheers,

Comment: As noted, you can probably achieve this by subclassing Phone or perhaps by using an @Where clause on the associations. However, as noted above, why bother? How much processing time do you imagine you'd save for the average person with 3 or 4 or phone numbers. See: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization